# Different uPort provider

Tags: infura, web3-providers, uport

I'm trying to integrate uPort in one of my project and, the first thing that I noticed are the different ways to give a provider:

1. from the official repository [uPort-lib](https://github.com/ConsenSys/uport-lib)

   `let web3 = uport.getWeb3()`
2. from the [official example](https://github.com/ConsenSys/uport-lib/blob/develop/examples/example.html)

   `let rpcUrl = "https://consensysnet.infura.io:8545";
   let Uport = window.uportlib.Uport;
     let web3 = new Web3();
     // App options
     let options = {
       ipfsProvider: {
         host: 'ipfs.infura.io',
         port: '5001',
         protocol: 'https',
         root: ''
       }
     }
     let uport = new Uport(appName, options)
     let uportProvider = uport.getUportProvider(rpcUrl)
     web3.setProvider(uportProvider)`

and after

`let uport = new Uport('TEST92184091284091284')
 let web3 = uport.getWeb3()`

3. from [uPort test-app](https://github.com/ConsenSys/uport-testapp)

`let web3 = new Web3()
let options = {
  ipfsProvider: {
    host: 'ipfs.infura.io',
    port: '5001',
    protocol: 'https',
    root: ''
  }
}
let uport = new Uport('TestApp', options)
let uportProvider = uport.getUportProvider('https://ropsten.infura.io:8545')
web3.setProvider(uportProvider)`

In .1 which provider? https://ipfs.infura.io:5001?

In .2 uPort use https://ipfs.infura.io:5001 or https://consensysnet.infura.io:8545 ?

In .3 https://ipfs.infura.io:5001 or https://ropsten.infura.io:8545

and... what happen if I use my provider :) https://ropsten.infura.io/myKey?

Comment: FYI, INFURA no longer supports Consensysnet.

Comment: consensys libraries no longer exist.